# header information showing instead of page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache

when loading query results into a page using jquery load() I recieve header information and funny characters on my page. What could be the cause of this? In addition to this Firefox and Chrome only show this error. IE8 is fine. When clicking around the site instead of opening pages, the download dialogue opens - which tries to download a similar looking file to the 'funny characters' in the jquery results. This problem seems to be linked.

Comment: Probably the code. Let's see some.

Comment: Can you post your ajax script as well as the php script that is sending the response?

Comment: What is 'ajax load()'? Do you mean the jQuery function?

Comment: We also need to see what you're calling a "header". It sounds like your webserver isn't processing scripts but instead delivering the files for download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance mod_deflate caused output errors and no actual code is at error. Turning off the module removes the error.

Answer (score 0):

"funny characters" => UTF8-BOM? (Usually showing up as 'ï»¿')